# MySQL query WHERE with object as result

Tags: mysql, node.js, objectdatasource

I'm searching `data.mesaj` in mySQL query but connection is running cause query isn't running, what will do now also `data.mesaj` have, but I don't want this:

```
data = { mesaj: '\nHello', uid: 'mustafa' }
```

---

```
y=data.mesaj;
var row = [];
connection.query('select * from yapay_zeka where yapay_zeka.soru = y ', function (err, rows) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        if (rows.length) {
            for (var i = 0, len = rows.length; i < len; i++) {
                row[i] = rows[i];
                console.log(row);
            }  
        }
    }
```

Comment: and error is `{ [Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'y' in 'where clause']
  code: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR',
  errno: 1054,
  sqlState: '42S22',
  index: 0 }
`

Comment: Instead of burying important information in the comments, [edit] your question to provide it there instead, where it can be seen and properly formatted.

Answer (score 1):

```js
    
 connection.query("SELECT * from yapay_zeka WHERE yapay_zeka = '"+y+"'", 
          function(err, data) {});
```

```js
    
 connection.query("SELECT * from yapay_zeka WHERE yapay_zeka = '"+y+"'", 
          function(err, data) {});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it:

```
connection.query("select * from yapay_zeka where yapay_zeka.soru = ?',[data.mesaj]
```